# VSTS build Specflow error have 3.0 installed but it is trying to use 1.9

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium-webdriver, bdd, specflow

I have written a feature file in my selenium C# framework
I have Specflow 3.0 installed when I build my project I get the error:

```
#error: 'Version conflict - SpecFlow Visual Studio extension attempted to use SpecFlow code-behind generator 1.9, but project 'Test' references SpecFlow 3.0.' D:\Selenium Projects\CompanyName\Tests\\Login.feature.cs 1 Active
```

Why is it trying to reference version 1.9 I have only installed version 3.0.213

How do I resolve this please?

I have unloaded the project and searched for 1.9 in the csproj file.  There is no reference to 1.9

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the [SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation/) NuGet package for your test project. It enables the code-behind generation at compile time, which should fix the version conflicts. I would go even further and delete all feature, feature.cs and step files and create them again in a new project to see if the error is reproduced.

Answer (score 0):

First of all check in NuGet package Manager if SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation have the same version as SpecFlow package.
If that doesn't help access your .feature file properties and remove entry from Custom Tool field.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on my VS 2017, you only have to deactivate this option in VS:

[image]